# How to "skip" blank input when dealing with math? (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, math, input

I'm working on a GPA calculator to get familiar with python/programming. I have it working when there is an input for every class. However, I am not sure how I would make the variable be skipped if nothing is entered for a classes credits/grade, or make it act as a blank number.

I have tried adding a blank string to a dictionary and setting it equal to None, but I still get an error.

```
grades = {
    'A+' : 4.00,
    'A' : 4.00,
    'A-' : 3.67,
    'B+' : 3.33,
    'B' : 3.00,
    'B-' : 2.67,
    'C+' : 2.33,
    'C' : 2.0,
    'C-' : 1.67,
    'D+' : 1.33,
    'D' : 1.0,
    'F' : 0.0,
    }

grd_num = []
cred = []

grd_num.append(grades[input('Enter the letter grade for your first class\n')])
cred.append(float(input('Enter the amount of credits that your first class is worth\n')))

grd_num.append(grades[input('Enter the letter grade for your second class\n')])
cred.append(float(input('Enter the amount of credits that your second class is worth\n')))

grd_num.append(grades[input('Enter the letter grade for your third class\n')])
cred.append(float(input('Enter the amount of credits that your third class is worth\n')))

grd_num.append(grades[input('Enter the letter grade for your fourth class\n')])
cred.append(float(input('Enter the amount of credits that your fourth class is worth\n')))

grd_num.append(grades[input('Enter the letter grade for your fith class\n')])
cred.append(float(input('Enter the amount of credits that your fith class is worth\n')))

grd_num.append(grades[input('Enter the letter grade for your sixth class\n')])
cred.append(float(input('Enter the amount of credits that your sixth class is worth\n')))

grd_num.append(grades[input('Enter the letter grade for your seventh class\n')])
cred.append(float(input('Enter the amount of credits that your seventh class is worth\n')))

grd_num.append(grades[input('Enter the letter grade for your eighth class\n')])
cred.append(float(input('Enter the amount of credits that your eighth class is worth\n')))


totGPA = ((grd_num[0] * cred[0]) + (grd_num[1] * cred[1]) + (grd_num[2] * cred[2]) + (grd_num[3] * cred[3]) + (grd_num[4] * cred[4]) + (grd_num[5] * cred[5]) + (grd_num[6] * cred[6]) + (grd_num[7] * cred[7]))/sum(cred)

print(totGPA)
```

I want to users to be able to enter as many classes as they'd like, from 1 to 8. Right now, it is only possible for user to enter 8 classes without error.

Comment: First prompt for # of inputs, then use a loop.

Comment: I think, then, you need to read a good Python book or some tutorials about using an extra variable, as well as `for` loops.

Comment: Very true, I was just trying to complete it using what I have learned so far. Thank you for your help! Do you know if there would be any way of doing this without asking how many classes the user would want? And just leaving the unwanted classes blank?

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a workaround I can think of. You can check if the user input is empty and interrupt the input sequence accordingly.

```
grd = input('Enter the letter grade for your first class\n')
if grd != "":
    grd_num.append(grades[grd])
    cred.append(float(input('Enter the amount of credits that your first class is worth\n')))
else:
    grd_num.append(0.0)
    cred.append(0.0)

if grd != "":
    grd = input('Enter the letter grade for your second class\n')
    if grd != "":
        grd_num.append(grades[grd])
        cred.append(float(input('Enter the amount of credits that your second class is worth\n')))
    else:
        grd_num.append(0.0)
        cred.append(0.0)
else:
    grd_num.append(0.0)
    cred.append(0.0)


if grd != "":
    grd = input('Enter the letter grade for your third class\n')
    if grd != "":
        grd_num.append(grades[grd])
        cred.append(float(input('Enter the amount of credits that your third class is worth\n')))
    else:
        grd_num.append(0.0)
        cred.append(0.0)
else:
    grd_num.append(0.0)
    cred.append(0.0)

# REPEAT REPEAT REPEAT ...

if grd != "":
    grd = input('Enter the letter grade for your eighth  class\n')
    if grd != "":
        grd_num.append(grades[grd])
        cred.append(float(input('Enter the amount of credits that your eighth class is worth\n')))
    else:
        grd_num.append(0.0)
        cred.append(0.0)
else:
    grd_num.append(0.0)
    cred.append(0.0)
```

By checking if the user input is empty, you can effectively stop prompting for input and fill the remaining data with zeros.